# Convert UIBezierPath to String

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

when I NSLog an UIBezierPath object it shows the MoveTo and CurveTo details... so I wonder is there anyway I could convert UIBezierPath object to a string?

Comment: Please add an information, what you want to do with the string. Is it for debugging purpose or – i. e. – for storing it in a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a string as you see in the `NSLog` then simply do:

```
UIBezierPath *path = ... // your bezier path
NSString *pathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", path];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a human-readable string, you can do what @rmaddy said. But take care: It is for humans, not for processing.

If you want to have the bezier path in a processable format, you can think about serializing it. `NSBezierPath` conforms to `NSCoding`.